# Wrong date Apex error message

Tags: apex, date, error-messages

i want to make an this.addError with a condition on a date field this condition must get the error if the date is write in a wrong way like this:

19/13/2017

i have already an if condition in this way:

```
 if( null == (this.account.customdate__c) )
```

and i have it in my visualforce page but when i press my command the error don't appear but i cant' go in the next page's step

```
<apex:inputField id="IdR" value="{!Account.customdate__c}" styleClass="RemoveNone" />
```

How i can do?

Comment: Is your custom field of type Date?

Comment: yes @MartinLezer

Comment: Ok. So it doesn't work that way. The Date type value is independent from the way its displayed.

Comment: how your custom date is calculated at the time of saving?

Comment: what do you want to talk about? @SantanuBoral

Comment: I mean, whats the this.account.customdate__c value is showing at the time of saving?

Comment: If the field is of type Date, by definition, it is a valid date. You need to elaborate more on how the "date" gets into your system (VF inputText perhaps?). Then you have some apex tools to parse the date for validity

Comment: Dates and DateTime field values are stored in a system format because salesforce is architected to be used by users across the world in different languages and using other representation formats.  To change to display of dates users should change their locale. 

If you want to be rigid on the format you'd better use a text field with validation rules. But you'll be losing standard date/time field functionality if you do so. And internationalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I am not sure of the exact error that you are facing, but I think the below pointers will help you;

1. **customdate__c** is of type **Date**

If this date field you have included in you VF page like

```
<apex:inputField value="account.customdate__c"/>
```

then, when you click on any commandbutton or commandlink, it get validate itself before your action method is called and the error will be shown. You cannot handle it in server side because this value will never reach server side.
    2. **customdate__c** is of type **Text**

Then you can try

```
if(!String.isBlank(this.account.customdate__c)){
    try {
        Date.parse(this.account.customdate__c);
    } catch (System.TypeException te) {
        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Not a valid date.');
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg); 
    }
} else {
    ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Date value cannot be null.');
    ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg); 
}
```

From the code above I do think you are using it in a ApexController. In case of trigger use record.addError() in place of apexMessages.

Comment: i have it in my visualforce page: but when i press my command the error don't appear but i cant' go in the next page step

Comment: Add <apex:pagemessages /> in your page and try.